# Raspberry pytz not found if running at startup but ok in Thonny

Tags: pytz

On Raspberry Pi3B+, I have a program that uses `pytz`.  In Thonny the statement `import pytz` works fine, but when I try to run the program at startup, in `/etc/rc.local` with `python3` it can't do the import. When I remove the use of `pytz` in the program, it runs ok at startup. `pytz` was installed using `pip3`.

Comment: Could you add the line in your rc local, as well as how you call the script? Beware that `python` on the Raspberry Pi 3B+ defaults to the system python which is Python 2, where `python3` routes to Python 3.4. Make sure you are using `python3` in both your `rc.local` and to run the script.

Comment: the pytz is installed in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages.  In rc.local the command line is:  python3 /home/pi/logKW.py &.  This use to work fine until i needed  to use pytz.  All other imports work ok.